# How to add current date or current time stamp to a manual useradd script?

Tags: time, date, useradd

This script I made is manually creating a user by taking in only the name the user wants to use. I'm currently trying to add the current date or current time stamp when the user is created in the comments portion. If you look at the script where i have "date +%s" is where I want to print out the current date or time stamp. date +%s traditionally outputs the unix timestamp but i'm not sure how to make this work.

```
int=$(cat /etc/passwd | wc -l)
mkdir /home/$1
chmod 700 /home/$1
echo "$1:!!:17216:0:99999:7:::" >> /etc/shadow
echo "$1:x:50$int" >> /etc/group
echo "$1:x:50$int:50$int:date +%s:/home/$1:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd
#chown $1:$1 /home/$1
cp -r /home/dlodi001/. /home/$1
chown -R $1:$1 /home/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use command substitution `$()` as so:

```
echo "$1:x:50$int:50$int:$(date +%s):/home/$1:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd
```

However, your overall approach to scripting this is flawed. Why are you writing to `/etc/passwd and`/etc/shadow`manually ? Bad approach. There's already tools for that which do so in secure manner, in particular`useradd` command which is a compiled executable. Scripts can be modified by attackers with root level access. I suggest you abandon your script altogether and use appropriate tools for such job.

Comment: I'm aware of useradd, i'm doing this in a local environment to familiarize my self with the directories and how it all works. Your implementation worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo "$1:x:50$int:50$int:$(date +%s):/home/$1:/bin/bash"
```

Enclosing a command in `$()` will return its output